# Is the "Beyond the Frontier" spin off from the Lost Fleet one book or a series?

Tags: the-lost-fleet

The Lost fleet series by Jack Campbell has finished and according to wikipedia "The author however plans to continue the Lost Fleet series with two spin-offs: Beyond the Frontier, focusing on the main characters from the Lost Fleet, and The Lost Stars, focusing on the collapse of the Syndicate Worlds" - [The lost fleet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Fleet)

I have read "Beyond the Frontier - Dreadnaught" and I'm wondering if this book is the start of a series or a stand alone book?

Comment: Best books EVA!! Sci-Fi, humans, war, space combat, aliens, human nature. The spinoff books are just as good. I didn't expect it but they are! cant wait for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Jack Campbell's [own website](http://www.johnghemry.com/), "The *Lost Fleet - Beyond the Frontier* novel - *Invincible* will be published in May, 2012". So *Dreadnaught* definitely does not stand alone.

Comment: Grr, can't believe I missed that!  I was on the "the-lost-fleet-series" page of his website, but didn't check the home page!